# ASP.Net Web API Parameter is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I am using ASP.Net web api for my service, that is called from a third party application. When I test it in chrome postman it works fine in localhost and deployed server, but I have tried it in fiddler, hurl it and the string val is always null, should I be adding something else? I cant understand why it works fine in postman! Going kinda crazy with this one !
Thanks in advance

```
public bool PostProperty([FromBody] string val)
{
    try
    {          
        var reader = new StringReader(val);
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(property));
        var instance = (property)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
}
```

Comment: So... Where's the request you're sending?

Comment: Its a third party application that sends xml as a string

Comment: Okay. So where's the request? How is anyone supposed to tell you why a request doesn't bind without seeing the request?

Comment: The request is a string of xml, it works testing from postman, to localhost and my web server

Comment: You need to post the actual request, with headers. "It's XML" is not enough information to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Hi,It works fine in fiddler when I add the header "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8", the request is HEADERS

Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, compress
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 48313
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
User-Agent: runscope/0.1
BODY view raw

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><property d1p1:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="P:\edg

Comment: If I add the content type Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8, is there a way to make the api use this by default. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your signature to be

```
public async Task<bool> PostProperty()
{
    try
    {          
        var reader = new StringReader(await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(property));
        var instance = (property)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
}
```

or

```
public bool PostProperty([FromBody] property val)
{

}
```

If you do the second option, you might have to add the following line to your setup,

```
config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

Comment: Opps spoke too soon, now getting There is an error in XML document (1, 1)

Comment: changes to a streamreader, and now get Illegal characters in path., Help !

Comment: @user2332277 Which approach did you take?  If the first then make sure you are doing a Flush on the stream on the client side.